# Transform SQL Queries to SOQL Queries in a Lightning App

Tags: trailhead

I am trying to install package for [TrailHead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails/microsoft_dotnet/projects/transform-sql-queries-to-soql-queries-in-a-lightning-app/steps/set-up-your-trailhead-playground)  but it is showing error 
**`Installing this package requires the following feature and its associated permissions: Apex Classes
Apex Classes(classes/Books4EveryoneSampleDataControllerTest.cls-meta.xml) Missing feature`**

I have creating new TrailHead Playground but still getting same error. It is developer Org and All permission is already given. Please suggest, if anyone has faced same issue.

Comment: You're logging in to the wrong org, or you created a trial account instead. Make sure you're signing up from https://developer.force.com/ or https://trailhead.salesforce.com/, and not https://www.salesforce.com/. Also make sure you're actually logged in to the correct account.

Comment: I am logged in with developer account. infact i am able to install other packages.

Comment: Installing a package does not mean you have Apex Code. Try making a new class directly in Setup (Setup > Develop > Apex Classes).

Comment: Yes, I have created many apex classes for other trailhead modules.